# Share Image on Facebook and Force thumnail view

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I'm using a script that shares an image on Facebook. On desktop the image (440px x 450px) is getting shared in a large format and on mobile I'm seeing the small square thumbnail format.

I would like to always share using the small thumbnail format. I read that if the image is less 600px wide that the share usually defaults to the thumbnail.

This is the link of the page I'm sharing. If you resize the browser to mobile you see the thumbnail share.
http://www.paralanaturaleza.org/donateatree/thanks-en.php?name=Joe&donation=10

Any suggestion on forcing this format for desktop are appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Making the image perfectly square gave the result I wanted. 440px x 440px